# I want display image_url in php codeigniter using json array

Tags: javascript, json

The below code is json objects through database field values . How to display image in json the code is correct or not please verify it

```
$('#radio').one("click", function () {
    //    alert($(this).attr('id'));  //-->this will alert id of checked checkbox.
    if (this.checked) {

        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/secondpage/location",
            dataType: 'json',

            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                var jsonObj = data;

                $('#tbody').append('');
                n = jsonObj.hotels.length;
                for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {

                    var eachrow = "<tr>"
                        + "<td>" + jsonObj.hotels[i].name + "</td>"
                        + "<td>" + jsonObj.hotels[i].location + "</td>"
                        + "<td><img src='" + jsonObj.hotels[i].image_url + "'></td>"
                        + "</tr>";
                    $('#tbody').append(eachrow);
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The above code is javascript to display database values in table format .
then it displaying same as it is content but i want image also but it not displaying how to add image path to json table fields

Comment: *not displaying how to add image path to json table fields* ?!

Comment: k tell me  how to add image path to json table feilds

Comment: I hope jsonObj.hotels[i].image_url may not be the full image path, You may have to append the base_url

Comment: how to write please help me

Comment: what are the sample value of `jsonObj.hotels[i].image_url` and where do you put your image?

Comment: image2.jpg in array value image_url field it is located in assets/images

Comment: and also how to add div element with styles using json php

Comment: i did not get any answer